# Magento advanced search - inconsistent order of results / how to define multiple order-by fields

Tags: php, mysql, magento, sql-order-by, advanced-search

I'm finding that search results are appearing in an inconsistent order in Magento 1.9.0.1.

In [this](http://www.thinkinggifts.com/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?price[from]=0&price[to]=5&order=price&title=under_5) example below I've specified that the results should order on price, which works, but products of the same price are appearing in a different order each time I perform the search.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Two possible solutions (that I don't know how to implement) are:

1. To add a default, base order-by to all advanced searches (on product
   ID or SKU for instance)
2. Find a way of specifying multiple order-by
   fields, just like you would in a direct SQL statement, "...ORDER BY
   xxx ASC, yyy DESC..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I've fixed this by applying some extra XML to /app/design/frontend//thk/default/layout/catalogsearch.xml, see the "search_result_list" element below. This seems to have effectively achieved (1) above.

```
<catalogsearch_advanced_result translate="label">
    ...
    <reference name="search_result_list">
        <action method="setDefaultDirection"><param>ASC</param></action>
        <action method="setSortBy"><param>name</param></action>
    </reference>
   ...
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Kudos to [Adam-Allen in this stackexchange answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/44354/need-to-change-my-sort-order-for-search-results#answer-44633).